# How to add conditions into thinking-sphinx search query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have product model having price as attribute.

This query works fine but need to modify few things.

```
  @products = Product.search(params[:query], :with => {:price => (params[:price_start].to_s.to_i..params[:price_end].to_s.to_i).to_a}, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
```

I have some predefined price ranges, current price ranges are:

- 1-100 Dollars
- 100-300 Dollars
- 300-600 Dollars
- 600+ Dollars

Question is

```
:with => {:price => (params[:price_start].to_s.to_i..params[:price_end].to_s.to_i).to_a}
```

is working fine in case of (1-100), (100-300),(300-600). But how to filter for 600+ ranges. How to pass query  like:

```
 :with => {:price > (params[:price_start].to_s.to_i} ie the case when price > 600
```

I am verifying the user is not changing params that make a long huge array.

**How can i modify this query to pass > and < instead of array of price.**

Answer (score 4):

Thinking Sphinx only uses ranges, not greater than/less than symbols.

In my app I do something like this:

```
value = 23
MyClass.search("itemname", :with => {:price => value..0xffffffff})
```

Answer (score 2):

May be `:without => {:price => 1..600}`?